# How do I include C++ files in project subdirectory with Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, include

I am working on a C++ project that has to be compiled using a Makefile. The project requiring various sources and headers, I decided to organize them in different directories inside the project. My situation looks like this (fake example) :
[image]

In the main.cpp file I try to include a_bis.hpp with the line:

```
#include "a/a_bis/a_bis.hpp"
```

When compiling I get the error message a/a_bis/a_bis.hpp: No such file or directory.
From what I understood I need to add the -I flag to the compiling command. Here is what it looks like:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I"D:\C++\test" main.cpp
```

The path is correct, but I keep getting the same error. I tried other syntaxes ( -I/D/C++/test, -I"D:\C++\test"). Looking online I see the same syntax over and over again, which I already tried.

Does someone have any clue of what might cause this issue?

This project is a school project and I am forbidden of using any cmake tool. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Show your Makefile. If its too complicated  you may need to forget about your current project and instead produce a smaller [mcve] for the purpose of this question.

Comment: First, you should always use forward slashes never backslashes when working with POSIX-derived tools such as make and gcc.  So you want `-ID:/C++/test`.  If that doesn't work, then if you open a terminal and type `dir D:\C++\test\a\a_bis` do you see your header file listed?  If not, then you have the wrong path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, I found the issue. I am using the regular path of my Windows system but I executed the make commands using a WSL terminal. When executing the make command in a Powershell terminal there seems to be no problem using the syntax pointed out by MadScientist's comment (`-ID:/C++/test`).

Comment: I don't do Windows or WSL, but I think that if you want to access Windows native paths from within a WSL terminal you need to (a) always use forward slashes, and (b) translate the drive letter `X:` to `/mnt/x`.  So instead of `D:\C++\test` you would need `/mnt/d/C++/test`.  Anyway you should be able to find docs on how to do this, somewhere.